# What is the difference between eslint and vscode for creating an application in loopback4?

Tags: edit, strongloop, loopback, loopback4

What is the difference between eslint and vscode for creating a new application in loopback4 , while using the command lb4 app, and wherever we can use it?

Comment: ESLint is a linter and VS Code is an IDE, so it's unclear why you'd have to ask.

Comment: as joneshape said unclear, even Not related to loopback4. You can use any editor, if you wish use notepad or vim to develop.

Answer (score 0):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

The `eslint` option configures the generated project to lint the code using eslint. It adds `eslint`-related modules to `devDependencies`, adds `package.json` scripts like `npm run lint` and `npm run eslint`, and so on.

The `vscode` option adds VSCode-related configuration files (`.vscode/settings.json` and `.vscode/tasks.json`), see the templates in [packages/cli/generators/project/templates/.vscode](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/e73a236bb7be88259ded0ee1114baa1f7ac80a86/packages/cli/generators/project/templates/.vscode)

It would be great if you could contribute a pull request to improve our documentation for future readers, see [Application generator](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Application-generator.html) page and [Contributing documentation to LoopBack 4](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/code-contrib-lb4.html#documentation).